# Right margin exceeds

Tags: margins, hyphenation

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot,
]{scrbook}

%%%page set-up
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} %to get rid of hyphenation
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%times new roman
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% <- changed
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indent first paragraph 
\setlength{\parindent}{2em} %adjust indentation
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %ragged right
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
standard LaTeX commands to change the text alignment. Alternativaly you can use therrrrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttttttt

\end{document}
```

I need the latex to start the long word from the new line and do not exceed the right margin of 1 inch. Could you give me some help.
thank you

Comment: Why are you loading package `ragged2e`? It allows hyphenated ragged documents, but you disallowed hyphenation completely.

Comment: Just put `\raggedright` in your preamble and don't listen to the sharelatex stuff. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you suppressing all hyphenation, there's not much of a point in loading the  `ragged2e` package and using its `\RaggedRight` mode (which is enabled via the option `document`).

Instead, I'd like to suggest you use the instruction `\raggedright` and run `\setlength{\parindent}{2em}` *after* executing `\raggedright`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

%%% document setup
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % no hyphenation
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{2em} % *after* "\raggedright"

\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%times new roman
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}% <- changed
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indent first line after a sectioning header

\begin{document}

standard LaTeX commands to change the text alignment. 
Alternativaly you can use therrrrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttttttt

\end{document}
```